# Get number from a Javascript class code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, numbers

I am messing around with a button on the internet and have got part of my code working, clicking the button automatically only 133 times in a 200 millisecond interval.

```
var count = 0; 
var thingy = setInterval(function () 
{ 
    $('#btnEntry').click(); 
    count++;  
    if (count > 133) 
        clearInterval(thingy);
}, 200);
```

However, I want to be able to adjust it so it stops clicking on a certain number too. For example, the page displays what number your click is with the following code:

```
<div id="lblYourClickCountPanel" style="display: block;">
    <span id="lblYourClickCount" class="yourClickCount" style="display: inline-block; width: 185px; visibility: visible;">107,459
    </span>
</div>
```

where 107,459 is the number of the click. If I wanted to stop the code from clicking after the number 108,000; how would I do that?

I tried the code,

```
var count = 0; 
var thingy = setInterval(function () 
{ 
    $('#btnEntry').click(); 
    count++;  
    if (count > 133) || if($('yourClickCount').getClass() >= 108,000     
        clearInterval(thingy);
}, 200);
```

But it gave me a syntax error for the if || statement. I am also not sure if I am using the right identifier to grab from either. What can I do to correct this?

Comment: It helps if your code isn't all put on one line. getClass() won't return a number, so comparing it with >=108,000 won't work. Also, 108,000 is not a valid number; 108000 is. Your understanding of the `if` statement is not right either.

Comment: I solved one part of the problem, the syntax error with combining the if statement so it reads,

    if (count > 133 || $('yourClickCount').getClass() >= 108,000)

So what should I try to compare it to? Cause $('yourClickCount').Number() doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

The correct code:

```
var count = 0,
    limit = parseInt($('#yourClickCount').text().replace(/,/g, ''));
var thingy = setInterval(function () {
    $('#btnEntry').click();
    count++;
    if (count > limit)
        clearInterval(thingy);
}, 200);
```

Comment: You might want to explain where he was going wrong, rather than just spoon-feeding the answer.

Comment: parseInt is not what you want, it will see the , and stop parsing. First you want to remove any commas. parseInt($('#yourClickCount').text().replace(",","")) should do the trick.

Comment: @SnowInferno - yes, corrected just a few seconds before seen your comment :) BTW, the string replace only replace the first entry.

Comment: @AlexAtNet - Ahh, I hadn't thought about a required click count higher than 999,999

Comment: I think I am still doing something wrong, because it's not stopping at the number I want it to.

I have the If statement as 

if (count > 133 || parseInt($('#yourClickCount').text().replace(",","")) >= 112250)
        clearInterval(thingy);

But once it reaches the number, it doesn't stop.

Comment: The expression compares the number in span with the fixed number - so if the number in span is greater than 112250 the clicking continues, which is probably wrong. Try to use < instead of >=

Comment: No... still just breezes on by without stopping. It still only stops when count > 133.

Answer (score -1):

**Write as...**

if (count > 133) || if(parseInt($('yourClickCount').html()) >= 108000
            clearInterval(thingy);

Comment: Are you sure? I'm guessing you didn't try to run anything resembling this statement.